# How to get basic phone details

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to fetch some basic things from the phone such as Time, Country, Language, Theme Color, Name of owner & Number of phone from Windows Phone into my app

thanks

Comment: Good luck! Let us know when you get a problem, not a blog post

Comment: @sayse that is also the problem. I m not able to find the solution for getting these all

Comment: @Sayse and if you think this is a blog post then kindly give me the link of the particular blog

Comment: show us what u have done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Time:**

```
DateTime.Now
```

**Language:**

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

**Accent color:**

```
Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
```

**Owner name & phone number are not accessible, for privacy reasons.**

Comment: thanks for help but I have one question when I install watsapp to my phone its always show my number so how I can do this

Comment: When you install WathApps, the application asks for your phone number...